# vuejs: create v-row only for every x element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im trying to build a container, where every **3rd** element in the rendered array, should be in one **row**. If you click on one element, it should consume **one row alone** and should go for 12 cols, while the other cols should **maintain** its position. Please see example pics

If I do it like in my code below, its obviously not working as expected.
However, if think the main problem is, that all elements are in one row. But even if I would do the  `v-for` inside the `v-row`, is also not correct I guess. So, how do I create a element inside a v-for, only for every 3rd element? Is this even possible?

If not, is there a other way to achive my goal? Using `v-if`s here seems not to be right.

My code:

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col
          class="border"
          :cols="active == index ? 12 : 4"
          @click="active = index"
          v-for="(animal, index) in zoo"
          :key="animal.name"
        >
          {{ animal.name }}
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",

  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    active: -1,
    zoo: [
      {
        name: "Lion",
      },
      {
        name: "Tiger",
      },
      {
        name: "Elefant",
      },
      {
        name: "Bear",
      },
      {
        name: "Monkey",
      },
      {
        name: "Snake",
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>

<style>
.border {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
</style>
```

Initial state:
[image]

If you click on Tiger, it should look like this:
[image]

Which is hardcoded this:

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="border" :cols="4">
          {{ zoo[0].name }}
        </v-col>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-col class="border" :cols="4">
          {{ zoo[2].name }}
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="border" :cols="12">
          {{ zoo[1].name }}
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col class="border" :cols="4">
          {{ zoo[3].name }}
        </v-col>
       <v-col class="border" :cols="4">
          {{ zoo[4].name }}
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="border" :cols="4">
          {{ zoo[5].name }}
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",

  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    active: -1,
    zoo: [
      {
        name: "Lion",
      },
      {
        name: "Tiger",
      },
      {
        name: "Elefant",
      },
      {
        name: "Bear",
      },
      {
        name: "Monkey",
      },
      {
        name: "Snake",
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>

<style>
.border {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
    data: () => ({
    active: -1,
    zoo: [{name: "Lion"}, {name: "Tiger"}, {name: "Elefant"}, {name: "Bear"}, {name: "Monkey"}, {name: "Snake"},],
  }),
  methods: {
    setCols(idx) {
      if((idx+1)%3 > 1) {
        let temp = this.zoo[idx];
        this.zoo[idx] = this.zoo[idx+1];
        this.zoo[idx+1] = temp;
        this.active = idx+1
      } else this.active = idx
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.border {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        class="border"
        :cols="active == index ? 12 : 4"
        @click="setCols(index)"
        v-for="(animal, index) in zoo"
        :key="animal.name"
      >
        {{ animal.name }}
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and nice approach. Sadly, i cannot select lion or elefant if the tiger is active to change the active element